# Prevent Duplicate entries from Entering in textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I would want to prevent duplicate entries from being entered into the textbox. I tried with the following code, but it is always fetching the current value and not getting matched with the one stored in previous textbox. My HTMLs are getting generated dynamically so i think this might be the issue.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="serialNumber" class="seiralNumberValue" />
```

JQuery

```
        // Restrict Duplicate Serial Number in TextBox 

        $(document).on('blur', '.seiralNumberValue', function () {
            var currentValue = $(this).val();
           var currentId = $(this).attr('id', 'currentValue');
            console.log(currentValue);

            $(".deviceSerialNumber").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == currentValue && $(this).attr('id') == currentId) {
                    console.log("Duplicate Serial Number found");
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Change your each function class as seiralNumberValue

Comment: Hi tkamath99, if an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){

$('input[name^="text"]').change(function() {

    var $current = $(this);

    $('input[name^="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $current.val() && $(this).attr('id') != $current.attr('id'))
        {
            alert('duplicate found!');
        }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
      <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
      <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3">
      <input type="text" name="textn" id="textn">

</form>
```

Check this. I think this helps your purpose

Whenever a user enters something into a text box, JQuery loops through all the text boxes in the form and compares their values with the value that the user just entered, if a duplicate value is found, then alert the user.

Comment: Not this is not working. My textboxes are getting generated dynamically on button click. So the static thing would not work.

Comment: are you increasing with adding any value to name or id to the dynamically generated text box?

Comment: Yes ids are getting added and value too

Comment: Then on button click after dynamically input text box added. call the above function and validate

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
var currentId = $(this).attr('id', 'currentValue');
```

is causing your method not to work. It sets the `id` of the input element to the current value, but the jQuery instruction doesn't return an `id`. Essentially, your `currentValue` and `currentId` hold the same value, so we can then remove the variable `currentId` altogether.

---

**Example:**

```js
$(".serialNumberValue").blur(function() {
  var currentValue = $(this).val();
  $(this).attr('id', currentValue);

  $(".deviceSerialNumber").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == currentValue && $(this).attr('id') == currentValue) {
      console.log("Duplicate Serial Number found");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="23df4" class="deviceSerialNumber" value="23df4" />
<input type="hidden" id="abc1f" class="deviceSerialNumber" value="abc1f" />
<input type="hidden" id="dj54g" class="deviceSerialNumber" value="dj54g" />
<input type="hidden" id="l7h34" class="deviceSerialNumber" value="l7h34" />
<input type="hidden" id="h56hg" class="deviceSerialNumber" value="h56hg" />


<input type="text" class="form-control serialNumberValue" id="serialNumber" />
```